# Baseball Ticket Sales (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a visual basic application( w/ visual studio 2010) that calculates ticket sales. This one is been really challenging since i'm a newbie when it comes to visual basic.

I'm i'm having trouble getting the calculate button to 
Here are the instruction to get the costs from the functions and use them to calculate the total. Here are the instructions they give me.

1. User selects whether to purchase season tickets or single-game tickets
2. User enters the number of tickets needed and the type of seats based on whether they selected season single-game tickets.
3. User clicks the Compute Ticket Cost Button to display final cost
4. User clicks the Clear Form button to clear the response

I'm stuck on the calculating button. I just need to be able to capture the cost from the button and then use the button to compute it.

```
Public Class Form1
  'Global Variables
  Dim intTicketChoice As Integer
  Dim finalCost As Decimal
  Dim cost As Decimal

  Private Sub cboTicketType_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboTicketType.SelectedIndexChanged
    intTicketChoice = Me.cboTicketType.SelectedIndex
    Me.lstSeatType.Items.Clear()

    Select Case intTicketChoice
      Case 0 : SingleGame()
      Case 1 : Seasonal()
    End Select

    'Make Items visible
    Me.lblCostDisplay.Visible = True
    Me.lblSeats.Visible = True
    Me.lblTickets.Visible = True
    Me.lstSeatType.Visible = True
    Me.txtTicketNum.Visible = True
    Me.btnClear.Visible = True
    Me.btnCompute.Visible = True
    Me.txtTicketNum.Focus()
  End Sub

  Private Sub SingleGame()
    Dim seatType As Integer
    'Add List Items
    Me.lstSeatType.Items.Add("Box Seats $55")
    Me.lstSeatType.Items.Add("Lower Deck Seats $35")
    Me.lstSeatType.Items.Add("Upper Deck Seats $25")
    Me.lstSeatType.Items.Add("Standing Room Only $15")

    If lstSeatType.SelectedItem = "Box Seats $55" Then
      seatType = 0
    End If

    If lstSeatType.SelectedItem = "Lower Deck Seats $35" Then
      seatType = 1
    End If

    If lstSeatType.SelectedItem = "Upper Deck Seats $25" Then
      seatType = 2
    End If

    If lstSeatType.SelectedItem = "Standing Room Only $15" Then
      seatType = 3
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub Seasonal()
    Dim seatType As Integer

    'Add List Items
    Me.lstSeatType.Items.Add("Box Seats $2500")
    Me.lstSeatType.Items.Add("Lower Deck Seats $1500")

    'Price Items for Single Games
    If lstSeatType.SelectedItem = "Box Seats $2500" Then
      seatType = 4
    End If

    If lstSeatType.SelectedItem = "Lower Deck Seats $1500" Then
      seatType = 5
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  End Sub

  Private Sub btnCompute_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCompute.Click
    Dim ticketNum As Integer
    Dim totalCost As Decimal

    ticketNum = Convert.ToInt32(Me.txtTicketNum.Text)
    intTicketChoice = Me.cboTicketType.SelectedIndex

    Select Case intTicketChoice
      Case 0 : totalCost = SingleGameCost()
      Case 1 : totalCost = SeasonalCost()
    End Select

    'try and catch number textbox
    Try
      ticketNum = Convert.ToInt32(txtTicketNum.Text)
    Catch Exception As FormatException
      MsgBox("Number of tickets must be numeric")
      Return
    End Try

    'display cost of tickets
    Me.lblCostDisplay.Text = "The total cost of tickets purchased:" & totalCost.ToString("C")
  End Sub

  Private Function SingleGameCost(ByVal seatType As Integer, ByVal ticketNum As Integer)
    finalCost = ticketNum * cost
    'Price Items for Single Games
    If seatType = 0 Then
      cost = 55D
    End If

    If seatType = 1 Then
      cost = 35D
    End If

    If seatType = 2 Then
      cost = 25D
    End If

    If seatType = 3 Then
      cost = 15D
    End If

    Return finalCost
  End Function

  Private Function SeasonalCost(ByVal seatType As Integer, ByVal ticketNum As Integer, ByRef cost As Decimal)
    Dim finalCost As Decimal

    If seatType = 4 Then
      cost = 2500D
    End If

    If seatType = 0 Then
      cost = 1500D
    End If

    finalCost = cost * ticketNum
    Return finalCost
  End Function
End Class
```

the error is happening here :

```
If intTicketChoice = 0 Then
  SingleGameCost()
End If

If intTicketChoice = 1 Then
  SeasonalCost()
End If
```

with the `singlegamecost()` function and the `seasonacost()` function.

Comment: What does it do now?  Any errors?

Comment: I Cant exactly see what is going wrong? Are you getting an Error? where do you want the value to presented?

Comment: Shouldn't `finalCost = ticketNum * cost` be at the bottom of `SingleGameCost`, just above the `Return` statement?

Comment: Using global variables (especially with the same name as local variables) makes your code more confusing as well.  Try to avoid them, and they aren't necessary in this case.

Comment: I want the value in a label "me.lblCostDisplay.text = ..

Comment: I just need to figure out how to get the calculate button to show the price which is (number of tickets * ticket type) different types have different prices which is why I created the functions... (not sure if I did that right).

Comment: You need to store the Button Variable somewhere so you can use it for when your computing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the seatType as a Public Variable.
then once they select the Seat you set that Variable
and then use the variable when you are Computing.

Then return the Cost.

In the Compute Function

After you have got the final cost then

```
me.lblCostDisplay.Text = finalCost.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified this a little for you. Take what you want from it.
I have not tested it. Hope this helps... Not sure why the formating
did not come out quite right..

Public Class Form1

```
Private SeatType As Integer = 0

Private Sub cboTicketType_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboTicketType.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim intTicketChoice As Integer = Me.cboTicketType.SelectedIndex
    Me.lstSeatType.Items.Clear()

    Select Case intTicketChoice

        Case 0
            Me.lstSeatType.Items.Add("Box Seats $55")
            Me.lstSeatType.Items.Add("Lower Deck Seats $35")
            Me.lstSeatType.Items.Add("Upper Deck Seats $25")
            Me.lstSeatType.Items.Add("Standing Room Only $15")

        Case 1
            Me.lstSeatType.Items.Add("Box Seats $2500")
            Me.lstSeatType.Items.Add("Lower Deck Seats $1500")

        Case Else
    End Select

    'Make Items visible

    Me.lblCostDisplay.Visible = True
    Me.lblSeats.Visible = True
    Me.lblTickets.Visible = True
    Me.lstSeatType.Visible = True
    Me.txtTicketNum.Visible = True
    Me.btnClear.Visible = True
    Me.btnCompute.Visible = True
    Me.txtTicketNum.Focus()

End Sub

Private Sub lstSeatType_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstSeatType.SelectedIndexChanged
    If lstSeatType.SelectedItem.ToString.ToLower = "box seats $55" Then
        SeatType = 0
    ElseIf lstSeatType.SelectedItem.ToString.ToLower = "lower deck seats $35" Then
        SeatType = 1
    ElseIf lstSeatType.SelectedItem.ToString.ToLower = "upper deck seats $25" Then
        SeatType = 2
    ElseIf lstSeatType.SelectedItem.ToString.ToLower = "standing room only $15" Then
        SeatType = 3
    ElseIf lstSeatType.SelectedItem.ToString.ToLower = "box seats $2500" Then
        SeatType = 4
    ElseIf lstSeatType.SelectedItem.ToString.ToLower = "lower deck seats $1500" Then
        SeatType = 5
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnCompute_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCompute.Click

    Dim sTicketNum As String = txtTicketNum.Text
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(sTicketNum) Then
        Try
            Dim ticketNum As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Me.txtTicketNum.Text)

            Dim totalCost As Decimal = GetGameCost(ticketNum)

            'try and catch number textbox
            Me.lblCostDisplay.Text = "The total cost of tickets purchased: " & totalCost.ToString("C")

        Catch Exception As FormatException
            MsgBox("Number of tickets must be numeric")
            Return

        End Try

        'display cost of tickets

    Else
        MsgBox("Please input a ticket number.")
        txtTicketNum.focus()
        Return
    End If

End Sub

Private Function GetGameCost(ByVal ticketNum As Integer) As Decimal
    Dim finalCost As Decimal = 0
    'Price Items for Single Games
    Select Case SeatType
        Case 0
            finalCost = (ticketNum * 55D)
        Case 1
            finalCost = (ticketNum * 35D)
        Case 2
            finalCost = (ticketNum * 25D)
        Case 3
            finalCost = (ticketNum * 15D)
        Case 4
            finalCost = (ticketNum * 1500D)
        Case 5
            finalCost = (ticketNum * 2500D)
        Case Else
    End Select
    '
    Return finalCost
    '
End Function
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous issues with the above code. It needs **heavy** refactoring. But even without that, the question cannot be fully answered in the current form for the following reason - You are calling `SingleGameCost` and `SeasonalCost` without parameters, however they are declared with such.

**This code would not compile.** If it *does* compile at your side, there is some code you did include to support the question. If it *does not* compile, this is the answer.

Regarding refactoring, clauses like this:

```
If lstSeatType.SelectedItem = "Box Seats $55" Then
  seatType = 0
End If

If lstSeatType.SelectedItem = "Lower Deck Seats $35" Then
  seatType = 1
End If

If lstSeatType.SelectedItem = "Upper Deck Seats $25" Then
  seatType = 2
End If

If lstSeatType.SelectedItem = "Standing Room Only $15" Then
  seatType = 3
End If
```

Can be rewritten:

```
Select Case lstSeatType.SelectedItem
  Case "Box Seats $55" : seatType = 0
  Case "Lower Deck Seats $35" : seatType = 1
  Case "Upper Deck Seats $25" : seatType = 2
  Case "Standing Room Only $15" : seatType = 3
End Select
```

Even though, as written, value of `seatType` would be lost, because it is declared as a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

Strange. I'm getting no errors when I wrote the code, though I still have to write the Clear Code for it - but I'll go ahead and give the code I have at the moment.

```
Public Class BaseballTickets
    Private _strBoxSeats As String = "Box Seats"
    Private _strLowerDeck As String = "Lower Deck"
    Private _strUpperDeck As String = "Upper Deck"
    Private _strStandingRoomOnly As String = "Standing Room Only"


    Private Sub lblBaseballTicketSales_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblBaseballTicketSales.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub cboxTicketType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboxTicketType.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim intTicketType As Integer
        intTicketType = Me.cboxTicketType.SelectedIndex
        lstSeatingType.Items.Clear()
        Select Case intTicketType
            Case 0
                SeasonTickets()
            Case 1
                SingleGameTickets()
        End Select
        lblBaseballTicketSales.Visible = True
        lblNumberOfGroup.Visible = True
        lblTicketChoice.Visible = True
        lblTicketCost.Visible = True
        lblTicketCost.Text = ""
        txtAmountOfPeople.Focus()
    End Sub
    Private Sub SeasonTickets()
        lstSeatingType.Items.Add(_strBoxSeats)
        lstSeatingType.Items.Add(_strLowerDeck)
    End Sub
    Private Sub SingleGameTickets()
        lstSeatingType.Items.Add(_strBoxSeats)
        lstSeatingType.Items.Add(_strLowerDeck)
        lstSeatingType.Items.Add(_strStandingRoomOnly)
        lstSeatingType.Items.Add(_strUpperDeck)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCost_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCost.Click
        Dim intGroupSize As Integer
        Dim blnNumberInPartyIsValid As Boolean = False
        Dim blnTicketIsSelected = False
        Dim intTicketType As Integer
        Dim strSelectedTicket As String = ""
        Dim intTicketChoice As Integer
        Dim decTotalCost As Decimal
        blnNumberInPartyIsValid = ValidateNumberInParty()
        intTicketChoice = ValidateTicketIsSelected(blnTicketIsSelected, strSelectedTicket)
        If (blnNumberInPartyIsValid And blnTicketIsSelected) Then
            intGroupSize = Convert.ToInt32(txtAmountOfPeople.Text)
            intTicketType = Me.cboxTicketType.SelectedIndex
            Select Case intTicketType
                Case 0
                    decTotalCost = SeasonTicketsFindCost(intTicketType, _
                                                         intGroupSize)
                Case 1
                    decTotalCost = SingleGameTicketsFindCost(intTicketType, _
                                                             intGroupSize)
            End Select
            lblTicketCost.Text = "The total cost of tickets purchased: " & decTotalCost.ToString("C")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function ValidateNumberInParty() As Boolean
        Dim intNumberOfPeople As Integer
        Dim blnValidityCheck As Boolean = False
        Dim strNumberInPartyErrorMessage As String = _
            "Please Enter the Number of people Accompanying you (1-99)"
        Dim strMessageErrorTitle As String = "Error"

        Try
            intNumberOfPeople = Convert.ToInt32(txtAmountOfPeople.Text)
            If intNumberOfPeople > 0 And intNumberOfPeople < 100 Then
                blnValidityCheck = True
            Else
                MsgBox(strNumberInPartyErrorMessage, , strMessageErrorTitle)
                txtAmountOfPeople.Focus()
                txtAmountOfPeople.Clear()
            End If
        Catch Exception As FormatException
            MsgBox(strNumberInPartyErrorMessage, , strMessageErrorTitle)
            txtAmountOfPeople.Focus()
            txtAmountOfPeople.Clear()
        Catch Exception As OverflowException
            MsgBox(strNumberInPartyErrorMessage, , strMessageErrorTitle)
            txtAmountOfPeople.Focus()
            txtAmountOfPeople.Clear()
        Catch Exception As SystemException
            MsgBox(strNumberInPartyErrorMessage, , strMessageErrorTitle)
            txtAmountOfPeople.Focus()
            txtAmountOfPeople.Clear()
        End Try

        Return blnValidityCheck

    End Function


    Private Function ValidateTicketIsSelected(ByRef blnTicket As Boolean, _
                                              ByRef strTicket As String) As Integer
        Dim intTicketChoice As Integer
        Try
            intTicketChoice = Convert.ToInt32(lstSeatingType.SelectedIndex)
            strTicket = lstSeatingType.SelectedItem.ToString()
            blnTicket = True
        Catch Exception As SystemException
            ' Detects if a tour not selected
            MsgBox("Select a Ticket Choice", , "Error")
            blnTicket = False
        End Try

        Return intTicketChoice

    End Function

    Private Function SeasonTicketsFindCost(ByVal intTicketSelection As Integer, _
                                           ByVal intGroupSize As Integer) As Decimal
        Dim decTicketCost As Decimal
        Dim decFinalCost As Decimal
        Dim decBoxSeats As Decimal = 2500D
        Dim decLowerdeck As Decimal = 1500D

        Select Case intTicketSelection
            Case 0
                decTicketCost = decBoxSeats
            Case 1
                decTicketCost = decLowerdeck
        End Select
        decFinalCost = decTicketCost * intGroupSize
        Return decFinalCost
    End Function

    Private Function SingleGameTicketsFindCost(ByVal intTicketSelection As Integer, _
                                           ByVal intGroupSize As Integer) As Decimal
        Dim decTicketCost As Decimal
        Dim decFinalCost As Decimal
        Dim decBoxSeats As Decimal = 55D
        Dim decLowerDeck As Decimal = 35D
        Dim decUpperDeck As Decimal = 25D
        Dim decStandingRoomOnly As Decimal = 15D

        Select Case intTicketSelection
            Case 0
                decTicketCost = decBoxSeats
            Case 1
                decTicketCost = decLowerDeck
            Case 2
                decTicketCost = decUpperDeck
            Case 3
                decTicketCost = decStandingRoomOnly
        End Select
        decFinalCost = decTicketCost * intGroupSize
        Return decFinalCost
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Hope this Helps a Bit :)